# Accents in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, accents

When using BibTeX, I am happy enough adding accents where appropriate. For example

```
@article{key,
author="Th{\'e}venaz, Jacques",
title={Permutation Representations Arising from Simplicial Complexes},
journal={Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A},
year={1987},
}
```

However, if the above is an entry in my `bib` file and I use the option

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

in a LaTeX file, then this creates an error, as BibTeX naturally creates the key `[Th\87]` for this entry. Obviously I can go back to my `bbl` file and change the key here, but are there more general ways of solving this problem?

Comment: Using `biblatex`+ `biber` allows entering directly the accents, as bibr understands `utf8`. You just have to save your .bib file in utf8 format (you can do that with `JabRef`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct way, as far as BibTeX is concerned, is `Th{\'{e}}venaz`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{key,
author="Th{\'{e}}venaz, Jacques",
title={Permutation Representations Arising from Simplicial Complexes},
journal={Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A},
year={1987},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{key}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can read in Tame the BeaST about this: `texdoc tamethebeast`

Comment: How about á, í?, I tried `{\'{a}}`, `{\'a}` and `\'{a}`. None of those worker, what should I try? (I do not want to use `inputenc`).