# Writing accented letters in biblatex gives errors when also using the ulem and babel packages

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite a paper where there's an umlaut in the name of both one of the authors and of the journal.

I've looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57743/212208) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134116/212208) and I've tried:

```
@article{ResonantBhabhafor1980,
    Author = {Reinhardt, J. and Scherdin, A. and M{\"{u}}ller, B. and Greiner, W.},
    Journal = {Zeitschrift f{\"{u}}r Physik A Atomic Nuclei},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {367--381},
    Title = {Resonant Bhabha scattering at MeV energies},
    Volume = {327},
    Year = {1987}
 }
```

But I'm getting the error `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.` How can I avoid this?

In case it's relevant, I'm including

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
```

Extra context:
putting the umlaut in the author field works, putting it in the journal field doesn't

More context: i finally got a mwe going:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} % useful to change date format
\usepackage{csquotes} % prevents a warning with babel
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
As discussed in \cite{ResonantBhabhafor1980}, Bhabha scattering provides an excellent method to study the potential existence of a particle of this nature.

    \newpage
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

commenting either `\usepackage{ulem}` or `\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}` stops the error

Comment: I am unable to replicate the issue you say you've encountered using solely the information you've provided so far. Please extend your code snippet to create a [minimally compilable example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that generates the problem behavior you wish to fix.

Comment: You actually don't need `f{\"{u}}r` in the `journal` field, `f\"ur` suffices. I get no error, however. If you plan to use BibTeX in other documents, write `{Bhaba}` and `{MeV}` in the `title` field.

Comment: I also cannot for the life of me reproduce the error in a minimal example. All I can say is that when I replace the `\"u` with just `u` it compiles without errors, but when i put the umlaut back it give me the error above.

Comment: Just a guess, but  I suspect the problem is in a different .bib file item than the one you're showing.

Comment: There's only one .bib file in the project

Comment: I mean a different record of the bib file, not a different `.bib` file. But when I compile your example I get an error unless load `fontenc` with the `[T1]` encoding (using `pdflatex`).

Comment: @AlanMunn - which error message do you get?

Comment: @AlanMunn that works, post it as an answer and i'll mark it correct

Comment: @Mico "Extra } or forgotten \endgroup". I've reordered the package loading though, so that `hyperref` and `cleveref` are loaded last (as is usually good practice.)

Comment: Often `\usepackage{ulem}` is not what people actually want. More often than not people actually want `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`. But maybe you don't even need `ulem` at all: Underlining is generally disliked in the world of typography (or in the LaTeX corner of that world, anyway).

Comment: it was the only way i could find to get strike-outs, which is only needed in the editing process, not the final document, but is still useful. This is good to know though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiling your example with `pdflatex` produces an error

```
 Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
 \UL@stop ... \UL@putbox \fi \else \egroup \egroup 
                                              \UL@putbox \fi \ifnum \UL@...
```

This can be overcome by adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble.

In my example, I've moved the loading of `hyperref` and `cleveref` to the end, as is best practice with those packages.  In this case, `hyperref` must be loaded before `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel} % useful to change date format
\usepackage{csquotes} % prevents a warning with babel
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}


\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{ResonantBhabhafor1980,
    Author = {Reinhardt, J. and Scherdin, A. and M{\"{u}}ller, B. and Greiner, W.},
    Journal = {Zeitschrift f{\"{u}}r Physik A Atomic Nuclei},
    Number = {4},
    Pages = {367--381},
    Title = {Resonant Bhabha scattering at MeV energies},
    Volume = {327},
    Year = {1987}
 }
 \end{filecontents}
 \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\autocite{ResonantBhabhafor1980}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```